# When do I want to use static, final, private in swift 2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I kind of know when to use those different keywords, but can someone clarify for me when exactly do I want to use them, and how do they affect my apps during runtime?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

Answer (score 3):

> static

You use a static method or property when you need some data without allocating new object, the most common use of static could be the singleton design pattern or when you have some helper class.
So for example in a function you can call:

```
let temp = Helper.staticMethod();
```

where

```
class Helper {
     private let test1234 = false

     private func privateMethod() {

     }

     private static func privateStaticMethod() -> Int {
           return 0
     }

     static func staticMethod() -> Int {
          self.privateMethod() // Error
          self.test1234 // Error
          self.test1234 // Error
          Helper.privateStaticMethod() // OK

          return 0
     }
}
```

from `staticMethod` you can't have the access to NOT static method or property of the class `Helper`

> final

It should be best practice declare all classes final and remove it just if you have to subclass them. Final provides you a compile time error if you try to subclass a final class and so this can help you to have a clean architecture without risking to create messy code and it help the readability of the code as well.

```
final class FinalClass {
}

class Sub1: FinalClass {
} //Error

class Base {
}

class SubBase: Base {
} //OK
```

> private

A private class / property is not visible outside the scope.
It helps you to have a good encapsulation in your architecture.

```
class A {
    private let test = 1
    let test2 = 1

}

let classA = A() 
classA.test //Error
classA.test2 //OK
```

I suggest reading the Swift documentation for better explanations:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html